# Should I exchange my Scottish pounds for English ones?

Tags: united-kingdom, cash

If Scotland becomes independent, is there a risk that Scottish pound notes will become less valuable than non-Scottish notes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for specific investment buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?". See *[What topics can I ask about here?](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*. Also, you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?” See *[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.

Comment: I think given that it's about an entire currency and not about currency speculation per-se, this is a reasonable question. Also, while technically a "What if" question, it's a very real and plausible scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Scottish banknotes are promissary notes of the banks issuing them. Their value will be paid in UK legal tender any time as long as the issuing bank is in business. So they are not going to lose value unless the issuing bank goes bakrupt. Scottish notes may be refused, outside of Scotland, at least, by merchants at their discretion. So if the vote goes the wrong way, merchants in England may refuse accepting these notes even if just to make a point. English notes (those issued by the Bank of England) are the actual UK legal tender.

Wether you should change or not is up to you, I believe there's no immenent danger of them becoming worthless any time soon.

Comment: Even if the issuing bank does go bankrupt the Bank of England will honour the notes, because the issuers are required to hold enough English notes to back them (see http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/Pages/about/faqs.aspx#sandni). Also technically even English notes aren't legal tender in Scotland. After independence this may well all change but that's at least 18 months away.

Comment: If you have a lot of cash are the worst cases a) you have to drive to England with a suitcase of cash to redeem it (this seems odd but how else do you get the Bank of England to honour them in practice?) or b) you have to pay currency conversion costs in an Independent Scotland to convert to English notes.

Comment: If the vote is for independence and you want to hold rUK pounds, I'd suggest just going into a branch of the issuing bank and asking for Bank of England notes. It's not obviously the right thing to do - there's at least some possibility of a separate Scottish currency *appreciating* relative to the pound.

Comment: @Lembik Scotland will not become independent the day after the vote. The decision, if passes in the referendum, is only the beginning of a very long process. You'll have enough time to figure out what to do and where to live.

Comment: @littleadv True I am worried there is a risk that they will impose capital controls if the vote is for independence to stop everyone moving their money out of the country.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam What do you mean by the "issuing bank".  Normal Scottish notes don't name an issuing bank do they?

Comment: @Lembik Royal Bank of Scotland, who promises to pay the bearer. BoE in case of England, Wales & Northern Ireland.

Comment: @DumbCoder Thanks. Up to what level do they have to give you English notes in exchange for Scottish ones free of charge? Is it unlimited?

Comment: @Lembik Why do you want to exchange notes ? Transfer your account to a bank in the South, which is 7 days at present. If you take too many notes, it might make people suspicious. `English notes in exchange for Scottish ones`, not sure but I would believe unlimited considering Scotland is still part of the UK. But many banks might refuse the high denomination notes.

Comment: @DumbCoder IIRC, Northern Island banks can also issue notes. Only BoE in England and Wales.

Comment: @Lembik: they do name an issuing bank - that's the origin of the practice; the Scottish and Irish banks kept the right to issue their own notes when English and Welsh ones lost it. Royal Bank of Scotland, Clydesdale Bank and Bank of Scotland are the three issuers in Scotland.

Comment: @Lembik: there's no limit but you might have to provide identity and/or wait a few days if changing a large amount of notes.

Comment: @Lembik: the Bank of England has apparently promised to act as the lender of last resort for Scottish banks for the whole period before independence, which implies no capital controls. It'd be pretty impractical to impose them anyway.  I can't find a primary source, but search for "Mr Carney re-confirmed" in http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-29151280